# Why am I getting an error message for not declaring a variable in the scope in Arduino?

Tags: c++

I am making a UV Index Meter which I got from DroneBot Workshop (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBljvUBZqI8 at 32:16) and at the moment I have just followed the code he has used, however I am getting an error message. I have checked the code and it seems to be the same as in the video.

I have copied my code below.

```
// Include Wire Library for I2C
#include <Wire.h>

// Include Liquid NewLiquidCrystal for I2C
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// Include AdaFruit SI1145 Library
#include <Adafruit_SI1145.h>

// Define LCD pinout
const int en = 2, rw = 1, rs = 0, d4 = 4, d5 = 5, d6 = 6, d7 = 7, bl=3;

// Define I2C Address
const int i2c_addr = 0x3F;

// Define object lcd
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(i2c_addr, en, rw, d4, d5, d6, d7, bl, POSITIVE);

// Define object uv
Adafruit_SI1145 uv = Adafruit_SI1145();

void setup() {
  // Set display type as 16 char, 2 rows
  lcd.begin(16,2);

  // Initialise UV sensor
  uv.begin();
  }

void loop() {
  // Read UV level
  float UVindex = uv.readUV();
  // Divide by 100 for UV index
  UVindex /= 100.0;

  // Display UV Index on LCD

  // Clear the display
  lcd.clear();

  // Print on top line
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Uv Index: ");
  lcd.print(UVindex);

  // Print bottom line
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);

  if (UVindex < 3.0) {
    lcd.print("Low UV Level");
    }
  else if (UVindex >= 3 && UVindex < 6) {
    lcd.print("Medium UV Level");
    }
  else if (UVindex >= 6 && UVindex < 8) {
    lcd.print("High UV Level");
    }
  else {
    lcd.print("Extreme High UV Level");
    }
  
  delay (1000);
  }
```

The error message I receive is as follows:

UV_Sensor_v1:17:61: error: 'POSITIVE' was not declared in this scope
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(i2c_addr, en, rw, d4, d5, d6, d7, bl, POSITIVE);
^~~~~~~~
exit status 1
'POSITIVE' was not declared in this scope

Comment: We would need to see all of the code in order to have a context to diagnose the issue.

Comment: It seems you haven't `include`d the library. You have to include the directory of the file and the code to make us able to see if you really have included the library or was misplaced.

Comment: @Isabella Chapman Which header file are you expecting to provide a definition for `POSITIVE`?

Comment: @SCCC the LiquidCrystal for I2C - and for context they should be the pinouts on the I2C adapter that connects to the LCD display

Comment: @icuser A quick glance at the header file [here](https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library/blob/master/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h) does not show any defines for the symbol POSITIVE. grep for the POSITIVE string in your arduino include directory. I suspect the original author of the code would have modified one of the header files and defined this symbol

Answer (score 2):

Include these libraries in your headers:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_SR.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_SR2W.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_SR3W.h>
```

It worked for me.